# Why are certain bracket style/formats prefered in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, indentation

I've gotten the gist that the following

```
<T> my_function(...) {
   ....
}
```

is preferred by most, compared to:

```
<T> my_function(...) 
{
   ....
}
```

Likewise for:

```
if (...) {
   ...
}
```

being preferred over

```
if (...) 
{
   ...
}
```

Is this true and if so, why is the former style preferred over the latter?

Comment: My theory is that right-handed people prefer `) {` and left-handed people prefer `\n{`

Comment: I'm right handed and I've used `\n{`  but most of the examples I've been given on here tend to be `{` so I was wondering if i was doing something wrong (edit: in terms of style, not syntax, I mean)!

Comment: Add me to the stats, I prefer the former in either case. I think it's cleaner and it removes a lot of unnecessary lines.

Comment: Consider asking this questions on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: IMHO the former style is less used than the later in c++, while it is more used in languages like java and etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: @Johannes: "it works on my machine" huh ? I'm right handed and I really prefer \n{ (clearer)

Comment: Ohhh, @Alexandre takes it serious.

Comment: I definitely prefer the '\n{' lining up the braces is really useful when reading other peoples code.

Comment: @Johannes: I didn't mean to be rude, but I'm definitely *not* left handed (-;

Comment: Brace style was. Should be closed with extreme prejudice every time. And there is no style but 1TBS.

Comment: To add another data point, I prefer `)\n{` for function definitions, but `) {` everywhere else. And I hate it if I need to scroll a piece of example code on SO which would fit on 5 lines if formatted the "proper" way. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is popular mostly, because it is demanded by Sun (Now: Oracle) in Java

Comment: More subjective than objective

Answer (score 3):

This isn't necessarily preferred - they're different styles, and different teams have their own preferences.

Many people prefer the former because the code becomes shorter and more "concise".  Many people prefer the latter because it's easier, at a glance, to see that the opening parenthesis character was put in place.  However, these are both **preferences**, and different people prefer different things (and even different than the ones you displayed, such as using indented parens, etc).